# How to mount filter to lens without thread?

Tags: lens, filters

Disclaimer: I have never used a Filter or Lens Hood, so this might be weird question.

I plan to do some landscape photography using my Lumix G F1,7/20 mm MFT Lens. Unfortunately I just realized that this lens does *not* have any thread to screw something on:

[image]

Is there still a way to mount filters, maybe using some accessory?

Comment: The image shows that there are front threads, of size 46mm.

Answer (score 7):

Some lenses do not have filter threads, but the front of your lens does have 46mm filter threads. 46mm is not a very common size but you can order filters for it.

[B&H Photo Hoya 46mm NXT Circular Polarizer Filter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/900301-REG/Hoya_anxt46crpl_46mm_NXT_Circular_Pol.html?sts=pi)

[image]